# Как привязать к статье блога на Django несколько изображений?

Tags: django

Изучаю Django самостоятельно. Возник вопрос. Делаю простой блог: Главная страница со списком статей и собственно сами статьи. В статье есть изображение. Как реализовать так, что бы на главной странице можно было загружать другое изображение, а не дублировать то же самое. Единственное что пришло в голову это вот:

### models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sub_title = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    article_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=1)
    article_image_preview = models.ImageField(upload_to=2)
    content = models.TextField()
```

И это конечно не работает ((. 
Подскажите как можно сделать или хотя бы укажите куда копать.
Извините за возможный сумбур, задаю вопрос первый раз. Спасибо.

Comment: [Руководство Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/) уже прочитали? Главу про _отношения_ поняли?

Comment: Да, читал. Но если бы понял то вопрос не задавал бы.

Comment: Вам надо создать отдельную модель для хранения одного изображения и связать её с моделью Article внешним ключом.

Comment: Как то через ForeignKey нужно? То есть так же как я с Категорией связываю?

Comment: Да, через ForeignKey, но наоборот - поле должно быть в модели Image и указывать на модель Article.

Comment: Спасибо большое за подсказку! Буду разбираться дальше